# MCP23017 connected to raspberry pi not showing up until I remove and reconnect SDA cable

Tags: gpio, i2c, pi-zero-w-2

I am testing an MCP23017 I2C port extender connected to a Raspberry Pi Zero 2w.  I can get `i2cdetect` to detect the extender only after I remove and reconnect the cable going to SDA (GPIO2).  I have to do this every time I restart the Pi.

I have another I2C device connected that doesn't have this issue. The issue exists even if the second IC is not connected. Is this a quirk of the MCP23017, is it still working even though `i2cdetect` isn't detecting it? Is there a way to force resync on the MCP23017?

I have it connected to GPIO2 and GPIO3, gnd, and vcc (3.3v).  Any idea why the chip won't auto connect on startup?

Comment: Post a photo of how it is wired.

Comment: Will do. It's messy though

Comment: The address pins should be wired to Gnd/3v3 https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/how-to-use-the-mcp23017-port-expander

Comment: I was cleaning up the wires to take a picture and now everything is working.  I'm going to chalk this up to "Layer 1".  Instead of jumper wires I used pin connectors and I think they are more reliable.